# Create Template Custom Field Field in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I want add a custom field in a Sitecore template.

Field will be a drop down of hours (1 -23) and used to show open and close time.

Ex:  8am to 7pm.

How can I add a custom field for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a droplist field and set it's datasource to a folder that contains numbered items 1-23.

You could also just use a plain text field and optionally add a validator, or a date-time field if you actually want the time (+date) formatted.